# How to prevent activity to be launched during each test using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I have a class that intends to test the app UI, however, each time that a new method annotated with `@Test` starts the activity is launched again - I would like to launch it once and performs the tests in the launched instance. Is there a way to do that?

Test class example:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TestActivityHomepage extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 <ActivityHomepage> {

    private static final String TAG = "TestActivityHomepage";


    private ActivityHomepage mActivity;
    public ActivityTestRule<ActivityHomepage> rule = new ActivityTestRule(ActivityHomepage.class, true, false);

    public TestActivityHomepage() {
        super(ActivityHomepage.class);
    }

   @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        mActivity = rule.launchActivity(intent);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPreconditions() {
        assertNotNull(mActivity);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoadMoreCharacters () throws InterruptedException {
        RecyclerView characters = (RecyclerView) this.mActivity.findViewById(R.id.characters);
        int previousSize = characters.getAdapter().getItemCount();
        characters.smoothScrollToPosition(previousSize);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        int newSize = characters.getAdapter().getItemCount();
        onView(withId(R.id.characters)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(previousSize));
        assertNotSame(previousSize, newSize);
    }

    @Test
    public void openActivityCharacter () {
        onView(withId(R.id.characters))
                .perform(
                        RecyclerViewActions
                                .actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));

        assertFalse(mActivity.isRunning());
    }
}
```

Comment: The activity is launch every test so you can start from a clean state. Why do you want to share your activity state between tests?

Comment: Sometimes the content of the test doesn't require the activity to be launched againd (in my current case, this is what hapens most of the times). As my activity connects to a back end, it slows the test execution

Comment: Why testing the backend in your GUI test? Use a mock instead

Comment: In the ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 it calls the full activity lifecycle, I'm not sure yet how to mock it

Answer (score 0):

I would've test my back end using AndroidTestCase and my GUI using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2  (With back end mock)